# Modifying area of appearence of div

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I want to create a fullsite layout in which I can create subdivs into a preassigned position, WITHOUT positioning settings.

I've created a top, left and bottom wrapper which should always be fixed.
Example follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ca1uto5/

What i want is to make ANY divs, following the top/left wrappers to appear below top- and leftwrapper.

[image]

```
 <div id="topwrapper">hej</div>
 <div id="leftwrapper">hej2</div>
 <div><p>I want this div to start within the topleft corner of the white area, without any positioning settings</p></div>
 <div id="bottomwrapper">hej3</div>

 #topwrapper {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height: 100px;
background-color:blue;
color:white;
 }
#leftwrapper {
position:fixed;
width: 20%;
height:100%;
background-color:grey;
color:white;
top:100px;
}
#bottomwrapper {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color: orange;
color:white;
bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: Please explain better the layout you want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I am not a fan of your layout method this what you want is possible.

Firstly, you have not stated position values for your fixed divs so that needs to be addressed.

The, by adding padding top & left (top = equal to the height of your header) and (left = width of your sidebar) to the `body` we can ensure that all future divs start as required.

Note: I also adjusted the height of your sidebar so that it actually fits between your header and footer.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
#topwrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
#leftwrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
  /* 150px = header + footer */
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  top: 100px;
}
#bottomwrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="topwrapper">hej</div>
<div id="leftwrapper">hej2</div>
<div>
  <p>I want this div to start within the topleft corner of the white area</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit aperiam obcaecati dicta odit praesentium doloremque fuga soluta rem nisi aliquid. Ad earum non sit voluptatem!</p>
</div>
<div id="bottomwrapper">hej3</div>
```

Comment: Spot on! Just for the curiosity, what setup would be better to achieve the same design?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:fixed;` style from all your classes

Comment: As I, atleast tried to specify in my post, I need all the wrappers to behave as fixed.

Comment: ... so this won't be an option.

Comment: Can you post an image of how you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
#leftwrapper {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: As specified in the post, I need ALL of the wrappers, and I need them ALL to behave fixed. So this won't work.